# html two table same column width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two table 1st table have tr th as a heading of the table and second table have tr td the content of the table i my actual code i have given custom scrollbar for fixed table head.

So i want to assign the width of td as per td content to th .

Eg. If the second table td 2nd row text is get increase the first table th width set as per td content.
I try below code but not working

```js
function TableWidth() {
        var i = 0;
        $(".TableList tr").find("td").each(function() {
            $($(".TableList tr").find("th")[i]).width(
                $(this).width()
            );
            i++;
        });
    }
    TableWidth();
```

```css
.TableList {
width: 100%;
}

.TableList table {
width:100%;

}

.TableList table tr th , .TableList table tr td {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TableList">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>List</th>
<th>Format</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td>2123</td>
<td>USA</td>
<td>EXADAAAFAasdasd</td>
<td>PDF</td>
<td>24/03/2021</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>2123</td>
<td>USA</td>
<td>EXADAAAFA</td>
<td>PDF</td>
<td>24/03/2021</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>2123</td>
<td>USA</td>
<td>EXADAAAFAQEED</td>
<td>PDFRQRFAFAFFAAFSF</td>
<td>24/03/2021</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>2123</td>
<td>USA</td>
<td>EXADAAAFAHSDFSFS</td>
<td>PDF</td>
<td>24/03/2021</td>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any reason for the 2 table approach?

Comment: @PEPEGA The web application which i am working is 7 years old so can't make the html changes

Comment: What does the age have to do with that? Anyway, you can simply remove the <tr> with the header and insert it into the main table. Messing with the column widths is a huge can of worms you don't want to open :)

Comment: Here's how I'd do this: https://jsfiddle.net/5ksLmuoh/

Comment: do you have any kind of scroll event for that custom scrollbar?

Comment: @syduki yes the second table have custom scroll so the 1st table is in fixed position and second table can scroll down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first you should do for this to work is to add `table-layout: fixed` CSS rule for header table, then if you have an event for that custom scrollbar you can call `TableWidth` function in that event, if not, then it can be refreshed at a a fixed interval like this `setInterval(TableWidth, 1000)`. The `width` is set like this:

```js
function TableWidth() {
  const tlist = document.querySelector('.TableList');
  const th = tlist.querySelectorAll('table:first-child th');
  const td = tlist.querySelectorAll('table:last-child tr:first-child td');
  th.forEach((th, i) => {
    th.style.width = getComputedStyle(td[i]).width;
  });
};

TableWidth();
```

```css
.TableList {
width: 100%;
}

.TableList table {
width:100%;

}

.TableList table tr th , .TableList table tr td {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.TableList table:first-child {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.TableList table th {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TableList">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>List</th>
<th>Format</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td>2123</td>
<td>USA</td>
<td>EXADAAAFAasdasd</td>
<td>PDF</td>
<td>24/03/2021</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>2123</td>
<td>USA</td>
<td>EXADAAAFA</td>
<td>PDF</td>
<td>24/03/2021</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>2123</td>
<td>USA</td>
<td>EXADAAAFAQEED</td>
<td>PDFRQRFAFAFFAAFSF</td>
<td>24/03/2021</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>2123</td>
<td>USA</td>
<td>EXADAAAFAHSDFSFS</td>
<td>PDF</td>
<td>24/03/2021</td>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Also, you should deal somehow with overflow, `text-overflow: ellipsis` may be an option